# API to get course category in moodle

Tags: codeigniter, api, moodle

I am working on a moodle project. I have created course categories on moodle but i want to display this course i have created using webservice (REST to be precise). How can I do this please?

Comment: Can you put the code in your question ?

Comment: @msvairam I dont have a code for this please. I have re-edited my question incase you dont understand what i was saying.

Comment: Refer the below link for http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814 rest api in codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Moodle webservices to do this.
Please read the docs to see how to enable this for your Moodle instance.

After it's been enabled, you can use the test client available from Github as base for development: https://github.com/moodlehq/sample-ws-clients/tree/master/PHP-REST.

You should see if you are able to add this as library in CI, shouldn't be that difficult though.